# how to sum up values in Grails/GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I would like to **sum up** the total cost in a GSP page ,i get now a list of all values. im using the code below:

```
<g:each in="${costList}" var="cost">
    <tr>
        <td>${cost.amount}</td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

How can I do that in grails GSP page. thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
${costList.sum { it.amount } }
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, i tried but im getting something like this (423) and not the total sum equal to 9. idea??

Comment: @mesut your numbers there are stings ("4", "2", "3").  you would have to convert them first. `costList*.amount*.toInteger().sum()`.

Comment: yes indeed i changed from String to Integer and it works fine now. many thanks